# Xtext typesystem multidimensional arrays support

Tags: multidimensional-array, xtext

I am currently writing a parser for a Domain Specific Language using [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/). In order to check the validity of data types usage in expressions I also use [Xtext typesystem Framework](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/xtext-typesystem/).

I want to include multidimensional arrays in my grammar, and I have done it as far as Xtext is concerned, but I have problems with the type system.

My grammar about arrays in Xtext is the following:

```
ArrayType:
{ArrayType}(basetype=BaseType  (dim+=Dimensions)+)
;

BaseType:
PrimaryType | StructuredType
;

Dimensions:
{Dimensions}'['size=Expr ']'
;
```

An example of the above grammar is int[5] name; (well name actually isn't included in this part of the grammar).

Now, let's go to what I have done in the type system in order to declare ArrayTypes, according to [this tutorial](http://www.infoq.com/articles/xtext_ts) (type recursion features section).

```
public EObject type(ArrayType a_t, TypeCalculationTrace trace)
{
    ArrayType arraytype= (ArrayType) Utils.create(lang.getArrayType());
    EObject basetype = typeof(a_t.getBasetype(),trace);
    arraytype.setBasetype((BaseType) basetype);
    return arraytype;
}
declareTypeRecursionFeature(lang.getArrayType(), lang.getArrayType_Basetype());
```

So if I declare a variable int[5] k; the type returned is ArrayType(int).

What I want to do and I cant, is to include in the type the number of the array's dimensions. For example,

```
int[3][2] k; //this should be of type ArrayType(int)[][]
int[5] g;    //this should be of type ArrayType(int)[]
k[3][1]=3;    //must be right
k[3]=g;      //must be right
k=g;       //must be wrong
```

I am really sorry for the long message, but I dont know how else I could better explain that to you. I will appreciate any ideas!

Thank you in advance!
Kate

Comment: Well, I did it but not through the typesystem. I left the type system the way it is, and through the xtext validator,with many many ckecks, I count number of dimensions appearing when accessing an array, number of dimensions in the declaration, I compare and check for errors in expressions.